# Search and replace for WordPress when using https://

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I'm migrating a local WordPress site from http://localhost:8888/example to a live server.

When I usually migrate a site to a live server, I export my database from the localhost, import it to the live server via phpMyAdmin and perform a search and replace with [this tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases) to change the URLs from my local enviroment.

In this case, the live server has an SSL certifiate. Many articles (including [this one](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/ssl-https-wordpress)) says you should implement the following snippet via .htaccess to force SSL:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

I've performed a search and replace and replaced all instances of http:// to https://. As this is the case, do I need to set a rewrite condition in .htaccess?

Comment: Yes, you should relpace `http://localhost:8888/example` by `https://www.example.com`.

Comment: Thank you. If I'm doing a search and replace to change all instances of http:// to https://, does this mean I should still set the rewrite condition via .htaccess?

Comment: Not mandatory but you should force user to use `https` by htaccess also.

Answer (score -3):

Absolutely you should replace them with https, for a SSL enabled site, it is NOT just a good thing, it's the thing you must to do.

You can learn more about SSL in WP here: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-ssl-and-https-in-wordpress/.

or try this plugin to make your life easier: https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/

Comment: Don't just post links as an answer. If the URL changes then this answer will not help anyone in the future. You can have the link but explain the important parts in the answer.